# Why is my AABB vs AABB code returning false positives

Tags: java, collision-detection, physics, aabb

I am trying to do AABB vs AABB collision and the code is never finding a collision.

```
    private static boolean checkFullCollision(Entity entity, Entity entity1) {
    float[] amin = entity.getMin();
    float[] amax = entity.getMax();


    float[] bmin = entity1.getMin();
    float[] bmax = entity1.getMax();
    return  (amin[0] <= bmax[0] && amax[0] >= bmin[0]) &&
            (amin[1] <= bmax[1] && amax[1] >= bmin[1]) &&
            (amin[2] <= bmax[2] && amax[2] >= bmin[2]);
}
```

where I calculate my min and max.

```
    public float[] getMax() {
    final float[] max = new float[3];
    max[0] = position.x + this.max.x;
    max[1] = position.y + this.max.y;
    max[2] = position.z + this.max.z;
    //System.out.println(position);
    return max;
}

public float[] getMin() {
    final float[] min = new float[3];
    min[0] = position.x - this.min.x;
    min[1] = position.y - this.min.y;
    min[2] = position.z - this.min.z;
    return min;
}
```

Can someone help me please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

For people trying to implement an aabb vs aabb collision here is the code.

```
private static boolean checkFullCollision(Entity entity, Entity id1) {
// VERY INPORTANY. The max and min are centered at the origin(0,0) and not at the entities posititon.

     Vector3f aextents = Vector3f.sub(entity.getModel().getMax(), entity.getModel().getMin(), null);
   Vector3f bextents = Vector3f.sub(entity.getModel().getMax(), entity.getModel().getMin(), null);

   boolean x = (abs(entity.getPosition().x - id1.getPosition().x) <= aextents.x + bextents.x);
   boolean y = (abs(entity.getPosition().y - id1.getPosition().y) <= aextents.y + bextents.y);
   boolean z = (abs(entity.getPosition().z - id1.getPosition().z) <= aextents.z + bextents.z);
   return x && y && z;
}
```

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt I will

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt see my other [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/158748/116458)